# My REST API endpoint handles 50 req/sec with avg response time 1300ms - is it slow?

Tags: node.js, rest

My API endpoint fetches some data from DB and returns to user (2.8KB gziped).
I load tested this endpoint with 50 concurent connections per each second (loader.io, app hosted on heroku, build with node.js) and avg time was ~1300ms. Is it normal, slow, very slow?

I know that it depends on DB query time and complexity - I just want to know if this speed is good enough for production endpoint? It serves main content for single page app (in json format).

Comment: There's a rule that an e-commerce page should appear in max 10 seconds. Look: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/ In my opinion, ~1.3s is a bit too long. Have you considered some kind of caching?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what your api is doing and how many users you expect to be using your app, but generally IMO it seems too high. Nodejs usually is very quick and has low latency. Try to identify first what is your bottleneck (query too big/missing indexes/too much post-processing/heroku slowness/etc). Can you provide what DBMS you are using and driver/query?